# Property undefined when trying to bind to template in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

In my view I want to show status messages using Knockout.
The user has to wait quite a long time and I want to show to the user what is happening (and that there is still something happening) with these messages.

For this I created a function `showStatusMessage` which can be invoked from anywhere in the application to show a status message.
This doesn't work however because I can see error messages in the console `property  is not defined`

```
function showStatusMessage(message) {
    var node = $("#statusTemplate");
    ko.cleanNode(node[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(new StatusMessageTemplate(message), node[0]);
}

function StatusMessageTemplate(message) {
    var self = this;

    self.visible = message.isVisible;
    self.statusText = message.statusText;

    self.hide = function() {
        self.visible(false);
    }
}
```

When I want to show a new statusmessage I want to call the `showStatusMessage` function like this:

```
showStatusMessage({
    isVisible: true,
    statusText: "Loading your data, please wait..."
});
```

My template looks like this:

```
<div id="statusTemplate" data-bind="visible: visible">
    <span data-bind="text: statusText"></span>
</div>
```

In both the `showStatusMessage` and `StatusMessageTemplate` function I can output the value of `message` so that is not the issue.
It seems like a timing issue where the template is loaded with no data available.
When I remove all of the 'data-bind'-attributes from the template there are no errors in the console.

Comment: You seem to have a typo. Change `var node = $(#statusTemplate);` to `var node = $('#statusTemplate');`

Comment: Fixed the typo, but it still doesn't work sadly.

Answer (score 0):

In your *self.hide* function you set *self.visible* to false, in order to do this *self.visible* needs to be an observable.

Here is a working example:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
    init: function() {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.stopBinding = true;

function showStatusMessage(message) {
    var node = $("#statusTemplate");
    ko.cleanNode(node[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(new StatusMessageTemplate(message), node[0]);
}

function StatusMessageTemplate(message) {
    var self = this;

    self.visible = ko.observable(message.isVisible);
    self.statusText = message.statusText;

    self.hide = function() {
        self.visible(false);
    }
}

$("button").on('click', function(){
  showStatusMessage({
    isVisible: true,
    statusText: "Loading your data, please wait..."
  });
});


var myPageVM = {
  property1: "example"
};

ko.applyBindings(myPageVM);
```

```css
#statusTemplate {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 25px;
}
.hide {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
This is my page
</div>

<button type="button">
  Show a message
</button>




<!-- ko stopBinding: true -->
<div id="statusTemplate" data-bind="visible: visible">
    <span data-bind="text: statusText">Nothing here by default...</span>
    <span data-bind="click: hide" class="hide">Hide</span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Hi SuperPaperSam,
That still doesn't work, I still receive the error that `property visible is not defined`.

Comment: Okay. I believe the issue is you're applying bindings to the element with a different view-model. If you inspect the element with devtools and the chrome extension "Knockoutjs context debugger" you will likely see a different view-model bound to that element.

Comment: I went ahead and updated my answer with stopBinding, with luck that should fix the issue. Please update your code and let me know if its fixed!